# Unable to decode the JSON response

Tags: json, go, decode

I have the following response from a graph api

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Mohamed Galib",
         "id": "502008940"
      },
      {
         "name": "Mebin Joseph",
         "id": "503453614"
      },
      {
         "name": "Rohith Raveendranath",
         "id": "507482441"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "next": "https://some_url"
   }
}
```

I have a struct as follows

```
type Item struct {
   Name, Id string
}
```

I wanted to parse the response and get an array of Item, How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to update your struct like so:

```
type Item struct {
   Name string `json:"name"`
   Id string   `json:"id"`
}
```

and add a struct to represent the wrapper:

```
type Data struct {
   Data []Item `json:"data"`
}
```

You can then use `json.Unmarshal` to populate a Data instance.

See the [example](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example_Unmarshal) in the docs.

Comment: The other option would be to make the JSON and Go names match up character-for-character, but seeing as you don't control the JSON names in this case, and you can't make your Go names lowercase or the JSON API won't be able to use reflection to access them, this isn't an option in this case.

Comment: @dommage , That works thanks, Can't we do it without adding an additional struct Data? For each response I will have to add a struct like this then.

Comment: I'm afraid so. Idiomatic Go seems to involve lots of little type definitions. You get used to it :)